# Why do I get data from a PHP PDO direct query versus an error when using a prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am attempting to run a very basic query using PHP's PDO module:

```
SELECT product_id, product, unit_price
FROM products
WHERE type = *[some_user_selected_product_type]*
```

(The product type is a tinytext column in the database, and I'm requesting the data via an HTTP POST.)

When I run the basic query, I get exactly what I expect.

```
$type = 'widgets';
$result = $db->query("SELECT product_id, product, unit_price FROM products WHERE type = '" . $type . "';";);
$result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Yields the sample data I put in the database...

`[{"product_id":"1004","product":"dingus","unit_price":"22.00"},
{"product_id":"1005","product":"thingy","unit_price":"10.00"}]`

However, when I try to use a prepared statement to do the identical query, I get an error when I try to fetchAll, stating that the operation can't be performed on a boolean.

```
$type = 'widgets';
$query = $db->prepare("
            SELECT product_id, product, unit_price FROM products WHERE type = ?
            ");
$result = $query->execute([$type, ]);
// echo var_dump($result);
$result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Yields...

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\DM\db_utils.php on line 125

What am I missing here?  Everything I read suggests that the queries should yield identical results.  I even pulled the queries from the DB logs, and they are, in fact, identical.

3 Query

```
SELECT product_id, product, unit_price
FROM products
WHERE type = 'widgets'
```

4 Query

```
SELECT product_id, product, unit_price 
FROM products 
WHERE type = 'widgets'
```

Comment: What says `if(!$result) { echo $result->errorInfo()[2]); } `  (to be placed after -> execute())  --edit: $result, not $db

Comment: As the erros says $result is a boolean, is shall be FALSE. And therefor the query will have failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call fetchAll on the prepared query object, instead of boolean that gets returned by execute.

```
$query->execute();
$query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: OMG!  So simple!  I can't tell you how many times I glossed over that in the documentation!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

you are not binding params right remove `,` from array `[$type,]`.

```
$type = 'widgets';
$query = $db->prepare("
        SELECT product_id, product, unit_price FROM products WHERE type = ?
        ");
$result = $query->execute(array($type));
// echo var_dump($result);
$result_set = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result_set);
```

Comment: The comma after the final item is optional/irrelevant.  See [PHP: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

```
$result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: error is not complaining on how to do fetchAll. $result is a boolean (false) so query failed

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$type = 'widgets';
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT product_id, product, unit_price FROM products WHERE type =?");
$query->bindParam(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
// echo var_dump($result);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo json_encode($result);
```